# InsertAfter doesn't work

Tags: jquery, insertafter

I try to insertAfter on a given element:

```
var design = "<span id='Umsatz'></span><span id='Paxe'></span><span id='UmsatzPaxe'></span>";
$.each(retValueStart, function (i, e) {
    //Umsatz
    var htmlRow = "";
    htmlRow += "<tr>";
    htmlRow += "<td>" + e.saison + "</td>";
    htmlRow += "<td>" + e.gj + "</td>";
    htmlRow += "<td>" + cMoney(e.summe_umsatz) + "</td>";
    htmlRow += "<td>T€</td>";
    htmlRow += "</tr>";
    $(htmlRow).insertAfter($(design).find('#Úmsatz'));

  //do other things
```

it simply doesn't work...

Ideas?

Comment: `htmlRow` is not a jQuery selector so `$(htmlRow)` can't find anything.

Comment: are you inserting it in the dom?

Comment: Note that there is a typo: `#Úmsatz `is not `id="Umsatz"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the comments in code. Also, I've highlighted the modified code.

```
var design = "<span id='Umsatz'></span><span id='Paxe'></span><span id='UmsatzPaxe'></span>";
$(design).appendTo('body'); // Append to body first
// ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

$.each(retValueStart, function(i, e) {
    //Umsatz
    var htmlRow = "";
    htmlRow += "<tr>";
    htmlRow += "<td>" + e.saison + "</td>";
    htmlRow += "<td>" + e.gj + "</td>";
    htmlRow += "<td>" + cMoney(e.summe_umsatz) + "</td>";
    htmlRow += "<td>T€</td>";
    htmlRow += "</tr>";
    $(htmlRow).insertAfter('#Umsatz'); // Don't need find here because ids are unique
    //                      ^^^^^^^^
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are trying to insert html after your `span` with `id='Umsatz'`.

replace:

```
$(htmlRow).insertAfter($(design).find('#Úmsatz'));
```

with:

```
$("#Umsatz").append(htmlRow);
```